# The requested URL was not found on this server in Joomla

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, joomla3.0, sobipro

I have a Joomla 3.6.5 version site and it use multi-language module using Sobipro directory component for Joomla. I Configure the file and set the database. Database connection is established properly. Now the issue is, the home page loaded perfectly but trying to access listed menu section  and other inner links the pages show the requested URL was not found on this server.Can any one has the solution for this.

Comment: mod_rewrite ON or OFF ?

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is ON

Comment: did u update your htaccess ?

Comment: is it working on your local server ?

Comment: can i know your project is localhost or live server

Comment: its on localhost. In live its working fine,but need to update some features so trying to install in local I faced this error

Comment: Admin-->System-->Global config-->Server-->Error Reporting-->developement , if u got any error

Comment: This is an htaccess file permission error, Root --> find the .htaccess to change  htaccess.txt or remove the file

Comment: yes got error at home page . This site can’t be reached. Now the administrator side is down. what I do to revert it ?

Comment: Can you remove  htaccess file from your root folder

Comment: remove the htaccess file

Comment: Set 'No' from  --- Admin-->System-->Global config-->site-->Search Engine Friendly URLs-->No

Comment: no change as I remove htaccess file. Now I cannot entry to admin side when I change  
Admin-->System-->Global config-->Server-->Error Reporting-->developement